# In-app updates not working due to playstore cache issue

Tags: android, in-app-update

In-app updates is not visible to my app user's due to playstore cache issue. My user are not able to timely update the app. What is solution to this ? not everytime i can tell my user to clear cache of playstore.

How can i get a callback in which i can remove cache and sharedpreference on app update. either its autoupdate from playstore or they manually click on update button on playstore. is there is way to capture those events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not immediate so your users should wait until google play detect the update and notify your users. It also depends on how you set up your distribution on Google play console.
Users can delete the cache going to `Settings/Apps/Google Play Store/Storage -> Clear Cache`