# Why android in-app update stopped working after some time?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-update, google-play-core

I have implemented an `in-app update` by following the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java). And it has been working perfectly for the past two months. But suddenly it stopped notifying the users about new updates even though the update was available on the `Play store`. After that, I searched for solutions, then someone suggested clearing the `Play Store` application data. I did so on my phone, then updates started to work as expected again.

Question: Do all the users have to do the same for `in-app update` to work again?, is there any other way?

Comment: I have also notice a bit of strange behavior with in-app updates. Most of the users on the app are updated to the latest version within 24 hours. Some outliers might take longer than that timeframe, but there are a very small minority of users who aren't updated to the latest (like 1-2%). Those user have the new in-app update mechanic in the app. I imagine if clearing the cache worked, there may be no other way to fix the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67627100/7367275